# Add regular JavaFX Node into FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

So I have a regular component extending from `BorderPane` and I want to add it into some FXML code. I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to coerce SettingsTab to class javafx.scene.Node.` `SettingsTab` extends `BorderPane`:

```
public class SettingsTab extends BorderPane { ...
```

I am trying to include it like this:

```
<Tab fx:id="settingsTab" text="%ui.gui.settings.title" content="SettingsTab"/>
```

The FXML code and the class are in the same package/directory.

I am relatively new to FXML and not very familiar with the syntax, so I am not sure how to do this.

I can include FXML files like this, but I want to include a class file:

```
 <Tab fx:id="scheduleTab" text="%ui.gui.schedule.title">
      <fx:include source="ScheduleTab.fxml"/>
 </Tab>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tab needs a content tag like this and not as an attribute value.

```
<TabPane>
  <Tab fx:id="settingsTab" text="%ui.gui.settings.title">
    <content>
      <BorderPane></BorderPane>
    </content>
  </Tab>
</TabPane>
```

And in your case:

```
<TabPane>
  <Tab fx:id="settingsTab" text="%ui.gui.settings.title">
    <content>
      <SettingsTab></SettingsTab>
    </content>
  </Tab>
</TabPane>
```

And you need an import in your fxml for your custom component:

```
<?import my.custom.package.SettingsTab ?>
```